# not able to display JAVASCRIPT RESULT on html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a function in JAVASCRIPT that calculates the HCF, in the VS CODE (MY CODE EDITOR) console it's showing the correct value, but I am trying to display the result on the page and it's not appearing and in the browser's console its showing maximum call stack exceeded.
The result of the **if** statement appears but when the **if** statement is false, the result of the **else** statement does not appear.

Here is my code:

```js
function HCF(a, b) {
    var answer = document.getElementById('answer');
    let value1 = document.getElementById('value1').value;
    let value2 = document.getElementById('value2').value;
    a = value1;
    b = value2;
    var ans = 0;
    if (a % b == 0) {
        return answer.innerHTML = `HCF: ${b}`;
    }
    var remainder = a % b;
    ans += HCF(b, remainder);
    answer.innerHTML = `HCF: ${ans}`;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Maths Problem</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Value 1: </h1><input type="text" id="value1">
  <h1>Value 2: </h1><input type="text" id="value2"><br><br>
  <button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="HCF()">Get answer</button>
  <h1 id="answer">HCF:</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You recursively call `HCF(b, remainder)`, but when you do, the values of `a` and `b` are overwritten with `value1` and `value2`. Your return statement also doesn't make sense.

Comment: Were is the *else* statement?

Comment: Thanks for replying,
So please tell me the required changes in my code.

Comment: Why are your HTML elements and javascript outside of the `body`?

Comment: @Ivan86 I tried with else statement too but not change in the result

Comment: @Ivan86 sorry for that there must be some mistake in copying the code, but actually they are inside the <body>

Comment: @PeterCollingridge please tell me what do i need to change?

Comment: Take the code that takes input from the document and puts the result back into the document out of the HCF function. Separate input/output from the calculation

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate out the code that calculates the HCF and which gets and displays values.

```js
function HCF(a, b) {
    if (a % b == 0) {
        return b;
    }
    var remainder = a % b;
    return HCF(b, remainder);
}

function getHCF() {
  const a = document.getElementById('value1').value;
  const b = document.getElementById('value2').value;
  
  const answer = HCF(a, b);
  document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = `HCF: ${answer}`;
}
```

```html
<h1>Value 1: </h1><input type="text" id="value1">
<h1>Value 2: </h1><input type="text" id="value2"><br><br>
<button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="getHCF()">Get answer</button>
<h1 id="answer">HCF:</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've separated your function into two functions. One function calls the other which is recursive and which returns the answer to the first function which then displays the results to the page.

```js
function HCF() {
    var answer = document.getElementById('answer');
    let value1 = document.getElementById('value1').value;
    let value2 = document.getElementById('value2').value;
    
    answer.innerHTML = HCFHelper(value1, value2);
}

function HCFHelper(a, b) {
    if (a % b == 0) {
        return b;
    }
    return HCFHelper(b, a % b);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Maths Problem</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Value 1: </h1><input type="text" id="value1">
  <h1>Value 2: </h1><input type="text" id="value2"><br><br>
  <button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="HCF()">Get answer</button>
  <h1 id="answer">HCF:</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Nimish You're welcome. Try to always create smaller functions that solve a single task, your program will be much easier to read, maintain and debug.

Comment: @Nimish you accepted my answer then removed it. Both answers are correct on the page, please select one if your problem is resolved. Thanks!

Comment: @Nimish btw, you can accept an answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).